# Angularjs controller as via typescript invoke controller function from a directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to invoke a controller function from a directive and I run into the "this" context problem. The *logSerivce* is not accessible if the function gets called via directive.

Here the controller class:

```
class MainController implements IMainScope {

        static $inject = ["LogService"];

        constructor(private logService:ILogService) { }

        sayHello(message:string) {
          console.log("MainController sayHello", message);
          // Cannot read property 'logService' of undefined if gets call from directive
          this.logService.log(message);
        }
    }
```

Here the directive class:

```
class TestDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        public restrict = "E";
        public templateUrl = "test-directive.html";
        public replace = true;
        public scope:any = {
            testFn: "&"
        };

        constructor() { }

        public link:ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope:TestDirectiveScope, element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs:ng.IAttributes):void => {
            scope.hello = () => {
              console.log("TestDirective", scope.firstName);
              scope.testFn()(scope.firstName);
            };
        }

        static factory():ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            let directive:ng.IDirectiveFactory = () => new TestDirective();
            return directive;
        }
    }
```

Here is a simple plunker example which covers my problem: http://embed.plnkr.co/Ov7crFZkkjDPzilX2BmL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are calling `testFn` from directive isn't correct way. To pass data with calling function you have to first use

```
ng-click="vm.sayHello(message)"
```

And while calling function from directive pass it in json/object format like `{message: 'some value'}` in parenthesis.

```
scope.testFn({message: scope.firstName});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://embed.plnkr.co/nd54cRZqMDtnVM4XXhog/)

Comment: Thanks lot! It works!! Unfortunately, your demo link doesn't show the update version. I changed the call: `test-directive test- fn="vm.sayHello(message)"` and the call in the directive. `scope.testFn({message: scope.firstName});` [Here is the new demo version](https://embed.plnkr.co/nd54cRZqMDtnVM4XXhog/). Thanks a again!

Comment: You might wanna update your first code with `fn="vm.sayHello(message)` too.

Comment: @stevo really my bad, I was feeling sleepy yesterday midnight, Thanks for pointing them out, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Methods that are supposed to be passed as callbacks (Angular binding fall into this category) should be bound to their context. For TypeScript the preferable way to do this defining a method as arrow function :

```
    sayHello = (message:string)  => { ... }
```